# Maximum recursive updates exceeded in VForm

Tags: vuetify.js

[vuetify playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpVj81OwzAQhF9l5UsTicbiT0jFicQDcENcCAeTbKgl/8neRKDSd8eOUVtOXmtn5tt5O7AYBv7kfbPMyHZMxCEoTxCRZg9a2s+2ZxR71vUWQBnvAsEB9nCEKTgDm2Tb/FsNLk0WLcVLDanpO+mycnA2Ehg3ooYWRpyUxef8Ex/OaZQWfsDOWndV/XjWB7QjhmSoamg72FdnTvP6gl8kA8psELxUSAcLQuO1JFyPF8t2csHAsl3Zqdf6/lVL+1Mi7FRM60Iq4KpOOsFPkpLIS2RG8QsWO16x2+auublmebhvHtj7Ly99eK8=)

this is all code:

```js
 import { h } from 'vue'
 import { components } from 'vuetify'

 const model = defineModel<boolean | null>();
 const render = () => h(components.VTextarea);
```

```html
<template>
  <v-form v-model="model">
    <component :is="() => render()"></component>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

this is error message:

Uncaught (in promise) Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.

it will be right when `:is="render"` or remove `v-model="model"`

Comment: Why you don't use a VTextArea directly?

Comment: the 'render' is originally props, but I wrote it this way in order to minimize bug recurrence.

Comment: Ok, so using `:is="render"` will fix it, I suppose. But I would suggest to use slots instead, if it is possible in your case.

Comment: I think your `model` should also bind on the `render` component, maybe.